# What do red and blue represent?

Tags: comics

*The Manhattan Projects* uses red and blue in clearly representational ways, but I can't quite figure out what they represent.

At first they're used to designate between the Oppenheimer twins, and later between alternate realities where things go right or wrong, so I thought they might be simple commentary on good/bad dualities, not unlike white hats and black hats to color-code the good guys and the bad guys. [I don't seem to be alone in this interpretation](http://polycomics.com/post/50119859952/red-and-blue-color-in-the-manhattan-projects).

But reading further challenges that simple analysis to the point where I had to abandon it as inconsistent with the text.

For example in Vol. 2, "Then. Iceland." red and blue distinguish between living beings and inanimate objects on one page, while on the next page one individual's panel contains both colors. Then individuals are shown in both all-red and all-blue panels on the same page and I gave up trying to figure it out and came here.

What meaning does *The Manhattan Projects*' use of red and blue convey?

Comment: I haven't read *The Manhattan Projects*, but must these colors consistently mean one thing? You say that they're used for different things in different places (twins, good/bad, living/inanimate) -- maybe they're just the author's way of differentiating *any* two opposites.

Comment: @Shokhet That'd be good fodder for an analysis, because *I can't figure out what the opposites are* in many cases, like the example in Vol. 2.

Comment: Oh, I see. If ever I read *TMP*, I'll give it some thought.